# Fluent NHibernate - how to configure for oracle?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Almost certainly a stupid question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

In the [Getting Started tutorial](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/GettingStarted:+First+Project) the database is SQLite and so his session factory creation
is done using the SQLiteConfiguration class in the FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db namespace

Great!  But I don't see a Configuration class for using an Oracle database.  How do I do this?

Cross-posted to the [fluent NH mailing list (with answer)](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/8a10a61a9a1d7581#)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me. Hope this helps!

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {

        var cfg = OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle9
            .ConnectionString(c =>
                c.Is("DATA SOURCE=<<NAME>>;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=<<USER_NAME>>;Password=<<PASSWORD>>"));

        return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(cfg)
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CLASS_NAME>().ExportTo(@".\"))
                .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void BuildSchema(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config)
    {
        // this NHibernate tool takes a configuration (with mapping info in)
        // and exports a database schema from it
        new SchemaExport(config)
          .Create(false, true);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're using the patch that was submitted since I posted this

Comment: Do you have an example of what the data source would be when creating the database?

Comment: It's just normal Oracle Data Source. This should help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400794/oracle-odp-net-connection-string-what-goes-in-data-source

Answer (score 3):

Does this helps you?

http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/persistanceconfiguration-for-oraclefluent-nhibernate/

**Edit:**  The code mentioned uses the ConnectionStringExpression class which no longer exists in Fluent NHibernate.  However, that class isn't used for anything other than holding the **OracleConfiguration _config** field. You can safely, add the field to the OracleConnectionStringExpression class and remove it.

The remaining issue is that NHibernate will now for some reason look for components that are not in the current build of Oracle.DataAccess.  If you want to deal with that you can do what tiredblogger did [here](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/using-oracle-odp-with-nhibernate-from-a-c-class-library/).

Comment: Where is he getting COnnectionStringExpression<T> though?

Comment: Someone submitted a patch, it is now configurable from FNH