# Oracle ODP.NET connection string: what goes in Data Source?

Tags: .net, oracle

This is the ConnectionStrings.com string of ODP.NET, great, but what is Data Source?

> > Data Source=TORCL;User Id=someUser;Password=son28dnn;

Is it a DSN in Control Panel?

A server name?

A TNS names service name?

Thanks

Luke

Comment: Did you read on the site right above that example where they have in big bold letters: ## Using TNS ##
? :)

Comment: Maybe we're seeing different pages but all I see between the example and a yellow box is "Using TNS" this doesn't explain what the Data Source argument takes. If it were TNSServiceID="blah" it might be understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ODP.NET with TNS which is nothing but one of the adapter for connecting to the oracle database.The file for maintaining the TNS Entries is Tnsnames.Ora

A Sample entry in tnsnames.ora(path for the file is normally ORACLE_HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN)sample entry looks like the below

```
TORCL=(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)   (PORT=MyPort)))    
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)))
```

Here TORCL is an alias for the Data source 
,MyHost is your Database server name or Ip Address,Port is the database listener port and MyOracleSID is your Oracle Service

Hence

```
Data Source=TORCL;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

is same as

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)  (PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Brackets, words and equals signs. Which are identifiers? Which are string literals? As a person that tries to improve yourself, consider improving this documentation. Consider how easy to use your code is. How easy was it to use the last API you wrote? Programming is hard. Let's be easy on each other. Think about the pain of using many technologies and how many shriveled and died because they were harder to use than some new, simpler paradigm. Consider why Apple suddenly took over the world.

Comment: I've added a new connection to this file but I get an error: ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error. Any reason for this?

Comment: Please refer this thread for explanation and to resolve the issue https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:424289000563